# Transport failed internal server error

Tags: publishing

I am having trouble with only one particular file and I believe it is because of the size. It is 13 MB, I have already increased the HttpsReceiver Maxsize in the cd_deployer_conf but this did not help. Any ideas?

Here is the exact error

> Transport failed: Could not transport tcm_0-510304-66560.Content.zip using HTTPS, cause: Internal Server Error

Answer (score 6):

In web.config file in HTTPUpload site do the following settings.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/.NetConfiguration/v2.0">         
  <system.web>
    <!-- This value is in **kilobytes** -->
    <!-- 512000 kilobytes = 500MB -->
    <httpRuntime executionTimeout="1200" maxRequestLength="512000" useFullyQualifiedRedirectUrl="false" minFreeThreads="8" minLocalRequestFreeThreads="4" appRequestQueueLimit="100"/>
  </system.web>

  <system.webServer>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <!-- This is the value in **bytes** -->
        <!-- 524288000 bytes = 500MB -->
        <!-- The maximum for this is 4,294,967,295 (3.99GB) - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4022434/-->
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="524288000" />
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
  </system.webServer>    
</configuration>
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: +1 This answer looks familiar ;)  Glad that it is proving useful! http://tridion.stackexchange.com/a/2199/71

Comment: It turned out to be a company specific policy that was not allowing the update of the web.config above. It took a while to track it down but once I found and modified it, the web.config file worked. Thank you.