# My pages in SDL Tridion 2013 are failing at the "Transport Phase" with Internal Server Error

Tags: 2013, publishing, dd4t

My pages in SDL Tridion 2013 are failing at the "Transport Phase" with the following error:

> Transport failed: Could not transport tcm_0-76295-66560.Content.zip
>   using HTTPS, cause: Internal Server Error

I have already implemented the following, as per [this](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/2205/transport-failed-internal-server-error) post:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/.NetConfiguration/v2.0">
  <system.web>
    <!-- This value is in **kilobytes** -->
    <!-- 512000 kilobytes = 500MB -->
    <httpRuntime executionTimeout="1200" maxRequestLength="512000"
                 useFullyQualifiedRedirectUrl="false" minFreeThreads="8"
                 minLocalRequestFreeThreads="4" appRequestQueueLimit="100"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <!-- This is the value in **bytes** -->
        <!-- 524288000 bytes = 500MB -->
        <!-- The maximum for this is 4,294,967,295 (3.99GB) - 
             http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4022434/-->
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="524288000"/>
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

But still it did not resolve the error.
Please let me know what am I missing. I am not sure where else to look for the error.

Details from windows event and IIS log:

> .NET Runtime version 4.0.30319.18444 - Loading profiler failed.  The
>   profiler COM object was instantiated, but the profiler failed during
>   its initialization callback.  Profiler CLSID:
>   'AppDynamics.AgentProfiler'.  HRESULT: 0x80040154.  Process ID
>   (decimal): 10984.  Message ID: [0x2505].

I am getting a warning:

> You do not have permission to perform this action.
>     Component: Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService Errorcode: 578 User: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE  StackTrace Information Details:
>      at Tridion.ContentManager.Security.AuthorizationManager.AssertAccess(IdentifiableObjectData securedDataObject, Permissions demandedPermissions, Rights demandedRights)
>      at Tridion.ContentManager.ContentManagement.VersionedItem.OnLoaded Tridion.ContentManager.CommunicationManagement.Template.OnLoaded(LoadEventArgs eventArgs)
>    Tridion.ContentManager.ContentManagement.VersionedItem.Loa

Comment: do you find anything in windows events logs, IIS logs?

Comment: Please change log level to debug/verbose and check for nay issues

Comment: whats that? and no error? check following post also http://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/326/tridion-2011-sp1-https-publishing-throwing-post-size-exceeded-allowed-limits

Comment: backup & clear your logs and publish again to find out error related to your problem.

Comment: Also, try after Restarting the SDL Tridion Content Manager COM+ Application, clear the cache (browser and server) and try again

Answer (score 2):

I think, you missed to update on deployer config as given in link

> [Tridion 2011 SP1 HTTPS Publishing throwing 'Post size exceeded allowed limits'](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/326/tridion-2011-sp1-https-publishing-throwing-post-size-exceeded-allowed-limits)

```
<HTTPSReceiver MaxSize="524288000" Location="D:\tridion\incoming" InProcessDeploy="true"/>
```

Please apply this and hopefully that should resolve your issue.