# Does Content Porter Run Differently on a Local Machine versus Server

Tags: 2013, content-porter-2013

Related to [Max size of Content Porter Import and how can we increase it](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/q/2196/46), I understand Content Porter uses the Core Service to export and import items between machines.

**Is there any difference when running Content Porter on a local machine (i.e. laptop) versus on a DTAP (Dev, Test, Acceptance, or Production) server in terms of time outs?**

Or in other words, can Content Porter use different Core Service endpoints based on where it runs? Based on below maybe we can configure a single endpoint for Content Porter?

The [documentation](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Content%20Porter%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-BA45E451-40C8-4E43-A2FC-9B2C90E39C43) describes a **channel** setting in the configuration:

> Note that if you change this port number, you must also change the
>   same value in the file web.config located in `%TRIDION_HOME%\Content
>   Porter\web\ImportExportService\`. In that file, the port number is part
>   of the URL in a url attribute in the following XML fragment:

```
<client>
  <wellknown type="comma-separated strings"
  url="http://localhost:50500/ProcessManager" />
</client>
```

The config "...also contains the Core Service client configuration for communication with the Content Manager. To configure the client, refer to the SDL Tridion platform documentation for more information."

**Also when importing, does the size of the *export* package matter in terms of `maxAllowedContentLength` (IIS) and/or `maxRequestLength` (.NET)?**

**Update**:

Based on Raj's answer and Bart's comment my misunderstanding was on the impact of the timeout settings. The *package* import, handled by .NET and IIS (and the above time out settings) is separate from the *Core Service* import/upload. See examples of the [Core Service timeout settings in this separate answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14386099/395495).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

maxAllowedContentLength matters because, your package is first uploaded on CMS machine, then import starts. i don't think timeout will differ as Package and ImportExportService exists on the same server in both cases.

Comment: So when Content Porter prepares the *import* package, is it the *entire* original export (ZIP) package regardless of what we select?

Comment: @AlvinReyes yes that is how the ImportExport service works indeed

Comment: Yes as @bart mentioned, entire CP package is uploaded & extracted @ contentporter\temp folder on server before actual import starts. then your selected items from that  package is imported

Comment: Much clearer, thanks. Last point so it's clear for me: if the export package fails on import when remote to a target server, it would still fail if the export package was *on* the server, right? Does Content Porter use the Core Service (and the `maxAllowedContentLength`) for both creating the import package and then to make the items? I'll update the question with this comment thread.

Comment: once package is uploaded on the server, then its between Core Service and DB(stored procs) to create the items in CMS. then maxAllowedContentLength should not matter. but if timeout issue occurs then there is another setting in Content manager config related to size which need to be updated.

Comment: I updated my question pointing out the part I wasn't clear on. So a fail on import doesn't guarantee a fail on the server. +1 and accepted, but feel free to add your comments to the answer. Here's an example of the Core Service timeout settings from @JRW: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14386099/395495.

Comment: As a follow-up, if doing a content port against, for example, localhost, you're still uploading "to the server" and the time-out settings in web.config for the Content Manager Explorer matter.

Comment: Yes, as those act as different processes.