# SDL Tridion Content Porter 2013 SP1 (Import Issue)

Tags: sdl-tridion, content-porter-2013, importexportservice

I'm trying to import the images using SDL Content Porter tool, and getting below error message while importing..

> An error(The request was aborted: The request was canceled.)occurred
>   while transmitting data over the HTTP channel.

I tried updating the `machine.config` as mentioned [here](https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/web/pub.xql?action=home&pub=SDL%20Content%20Porter%20full%20documentation-v1&lang=en-US#url=/LiveContent/web/search.xql%3Fc%3Dt%26pub%3DSDL%20Content%20Porter%20full%20documentation-v1%26lang%3Den-US%26action%3Dsearch%26query%3Dincrease%2520timeout&sid=lcSearch.runSearch1423097173512&currentQuery=increase%2520timeout&currentScope=&eventType=lcContent.loadDocGUID-D1C6115E-0E56-4153-9FE1-58E1D3DEE28F&query=&scope=&filename=GUID-D1C6115E-0E56-4153-9FE1-58E1D3DEE28F.xml&docid=GUID-D1C6115E-0E56-4153-9FE1-58E1D3DEE28F&inner_id=&tid=&addHistory=true&resource=&toc=false), but no luck. Please help on this.

Comment: when you are connecting to CMS server, its asking for Protocol and port. Try with HTTPS instead of HTTP.

Comment: and port try with 443.

Comment: are you not able to import any package or you getting error when you try to import any item on content porter , try with small package , may the package size is big

Comment: @AnandNS I tried importing few items, and that worked. I'm having issue while importing more than 10 PDFs.

Comment: Can you provide more information?

The version of Tridion (presuming 2013).

What are you importing (large quantity of files, large individual files, large total package)?

Is it consistent with a single item?

What's in event logs / Tridion logs when setting to verbose?

Comment: Please can you refer to this [post](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/11497/content-porter-2013-sp1-import-problems-http-requests)

Comment: @Sikarwar did you try the options provided are you still facing the issue.